# cmake install multiple targets single export

Tags: cmake

I have built and installed a cmake package (`Foo`) and was able to import it into another project (`Bar`) using `find_package(Foo COMPONENTS A B C REQUIRED CONFIG)`. In this scenario, `Foo::A` depends on `Foo::B` and `Foo::B` is actually made up of 3 shared libraries `Ba Bb Bc`. In `Bar` when I call `target_link_libraries(Bar PUBLIC Foo::A Foo::B)` I get an error message "The following targets are referenced, but are missing: `Foo::Bb`". If I then edit `find_package` and `target_link_libraries` to include `Foo::Bb` I then get an error "include could not find requested file `.../FooBbTargets.cmake`".

The code to export/install `Foo::B` is below:

```cmake
# using cmake 3.21
# Ba Bb Bc defined above as shared libraries
# Ba has the same name as B
# Bc is linked to Bb, Bb is linked to Ba, links are all public.

include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(
    TARGETS Ba Bb Bc
    EXPORT FooBTargets
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    INCLUDES DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}
)

install(
    FILES
        # list of header files
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}
)

install(
    EXPORT FooBTargets
    FILE FooBTargets.cmake
    NAMESPACE Foo::
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/Foo
)

export(
    EXPORT FooBTargets
    FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/cmake/FooBTargets.cmake"
    NAMESPACE Foo::
)
```

Ideally I would actually like to link to just `Foo` rather than having to list the components separately. It looks like my current solution is to turn each of the shared libraries in `B` into their own components and link to them individually but I would prefer not to.

Relevant part of top level CMakeLists.txt for `Foo`

```cmake
# our program only needs to support windows
set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON)

set(CONFIGFILEINSTALLDIR lib/cmake/Foo)
set(LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR lib)
set(INCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR include)

include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)
configure_package_config_file(
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/FooConfig.cmake.in"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/FooConfig.cmake"
    INSTALL_DESTINATION "${CONFIGFILEINSTALLER}"
    PATH_VARS
        LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR
        INCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR
)

write_basic_package_version_file(
    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/cmake/FooConfigVersion.cmake
    VERSION ${PACKAGE_VERSION}
    COMPATIBILITY SameMajorVersion
)

install(
    FILES
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/FooConfig.cmake"
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/cmake/FooConfigVersion.cmake"
    DESTINATION "${CONFIGFILEINSTALLER}"
)
```

FooConfig.cmake.in

```cmake
@PACKAGE_INIT@
set_and_check(Foo_INCLUDE_DIRS "@PACKAGE_INCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR@")
set_and_check(Foo_LIBRARY_DIRS "@PACKAGE_LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR@")

set(_supported_components A B C)
foreach(_comp ${Foo_FIND_COMPONENTS})
    if(NOT _comp IN_LIST _supported_components)
        set(Foo_FOUND False)
    endif()
    include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/Foo${_comp}Targets.cmake")
endforeach()

check_required_components(Foo)
```

Comment: The code you added to the question just creates the file `FooBTargets.cmake` which defines targets `Foo::Ba`, `Foo::Bb` and `Foo::Bc`. Processing of COMPONENTS and definition of target `Foo::B` is probably performed by your `FooConfig.cmake` script. Without viewing that script (or code which creates it) It is impossible to find out what is wrong in it.

Comment: I recommend using Premake (https://premake.github.io/). It is MUCH better!